# A quick generic question about eagle cad footprints

Tags: eaglecad

I am trying to make my circuit board using Eagle CAD and have found some ready made footprints of some 1206 size SMD resistors. Now I know 1206 is basically 3.1mmx1.55mm as a standard size however if I download one from the element14 website then the footprint is not made to scale(Its actually 132mmx68mm.) Is there any reason for this? It cant be useful in making a circuit and sending it off to a fab house because the size is incorrect.

Comment: 132mm x 68mm would be a *very* large component. Are you sure you've measured right? Are you sure that those numbers are not measured in "mils" (aka thousandths of an inch)? 132mil x 68mil is 3.35mm x 1.73mm

Comment: I bet Tom is right. MIL and MM are not the same thing. Also, as nice as it is to think that there's a part library on the internet for any component you may want to use, it never really works out that way. It's highly recommended you learn how to create your own parts in Eagle using datasheets. Making your own 1206 resistor would be a perfect place to start learning!

Comment: Ah you guys are correct! I got tripped up over mils and mm. I typed in 3.1 in mils format and got a tiny component! I wondered why I could hardly see my own custom made footprints.

Answer (score 1):

I think you miss type the size of the element14 footprint size. Any way, the footprint is always larger than the chip in order to make solder easier. You can find in the datasheet the recommended size of the footprint as well as more information about the soldering process : temperature and time exposure for instance. Since it just a recommandation, it may very from one manufacturer to another or from a "footprint designer" to another.

You just have to be sure that the footprint has the same size as the chip. If you try to do so, the chip may not be well solder and the solder will break due to many causes : vibration, temperature..

Comment: Yeah thanks for the advice I make my own footprints sometimes. I make the SM Pad at top tolerance end spec to ensure all sizes of the model fit.

Comment: Yes, sometimes, footprint are not provide by the manufacturer, so we have to do it by ourself.  You can accept the post if it answer the question.